# Argument of type 'Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob

Just got an error:

```
Argument of type 'Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
  Type 'import("buffer").Blob' is not assignable to type 'Blob'.
    The types returned by 'stream()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReadableStream<any>': locked, cancel, getReader, pipeThrough, and 2 more.
```

And can't understand what's going on. Tried to restart vscode but didn't help. `Blob` is not assignable to param of type `Blob`. ?! So `Blob` returned by stream is not the same with usual `Blob`?

This is my code

```js
    const audioBuffer = fs.readFileSync(`./uploads/audio/${filePath}`)
    const audioBlob = new Blob([audioBuffer])
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', audioBlob)
```

Error is showing when i'm trying to append file to formdata

Comment: Are you importing Blob or FormData from any module?

Comment: @RichieBendall i'm importing Blob this way `import { Blob } from 'buffer'` but formdata -no

Comment: What module are you using for FormData

Comment: @RichieBendall i'm using nodejs so it's already in ig ?

Comment: FormData is not a built-in in nodejs. Maybe the question could be expanded to include the motivation for using FormData? There's probably a conventionally different approach to doing this in node.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using two different types called `Blob`

The one you are importing is from node:

```js
import { Blob } from 'buffer' // this is from node
```

While the apis you are calling (`FormData`) are from the DOM and expect the `Blob` type defined in the DOM typings. These two `Blob` types are not the same

The fix is to remove the `import` for `Blob`. This should use the global `Blob` type defined in the DOM typings (provided you have explicitly excluded the DOM typings from your project)